# Ant.design - Automatically submit Form inside of Steps before going to next step

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

## My problem

I'm using ant.design in TypeScript and I want to put a [Form](https://ant.design/components/form/) inside of the [Steps](https://ant.design/components/steps/#components-steps-demo-step-next) component like this:

[image]

When a user clicks on the "Go to 2nd Step"-button, the form (inside of 1st Step) should submit. How to best propagate the information down to the form to submit it?

The following is a slightly modified version of [this code](https://ant.design/components/steps/#components-steps-demo-step-next):

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { Form, Input, Steps, Button, message } from "antd";

const { Step } = Steps;

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: 0,
    };
  }

  setCurrent = (value: number) => {
    this.setState({
      current: value,
    });
  };

  next() {
    this.setCurrent(this.state.current + 1);
  }

  prev() {
    this.setCurrent(this.state.current - 1);
  }

  steps = [
    {
      title: "1st Step",
      content: <FirstStep />,
      controlls: (
        <>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.next()}>
            Go to 2nd Step
          </Button>
        </>
      ),
    },
    {
      title: "2nd Step",
      content: <SecondStep />,
      controlls: (
        <>
          <Button style={{ margin: "0 8px" }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
            Go to 1st Step
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => message.success("Processing complete!")}
          >
            Finish
          </Button>
        </>
      ),
    },
  ];

  render() {
    let current = this.state.current;

    return (
      <>
        <Steps current={this.state.current}>
          {this.steps.map((item) => (
            <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </Steps>
        <div className="steps-content">{this.steps[current].content}</div>
        <div className="steps-action">{this.steps[current].controlls}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class FirstStep extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Form name="basic">
          <Form.Item label="Input" name="Input">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class SecondStep extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p> Second Step </p>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

## Good to know

The [antd documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-form-context) explains that we could use

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
```

and then

```
form.submit();
```

inside of a React Function Component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate every step you need to show for every step different `Form.Item` with rules and for every step validate form fields using form hook `form..validateFields()`.

This is example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Steps, Input, Button } from "antd";
const { Step } = Steps;
const { Item } = Form;

import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const App = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const handleClickNext = () => {
    form
      .validateFields()
      .then(() => {
        // Here make api call of something else
        setCurrent(current + 1);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 500, margin: "40px auto" }}>
      <Steps current={current}>
        <Step key={0} title="First Step" />
        <Step key={1} title="Second Step" />
        <Step key={2} title="Success" />
      </Steps>
      <div style={{ margin: "100px 10px" }}>
        <Form form={form}>
          {current === 0 && (
            <Item
              name="firstName"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: "Please input your first name!"
                }
              ]}
            >
              <Input placeholder="First Name" />
            </Item>
          )}

          {current === 1 && (
            <Item
              name="lastName"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: "Please input your last name!"
                }
              ]}
            >
              <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
            </Item>
          )}
        </Form>
      </div>
      {current < 2 && (
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <Button onClick={handleClickNext}>Next step</Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Codesanbox example:

[image: Edit red-lake-2fd4h]

Comment: When I asked the question, I only wanted to have a form in one step, but this is also really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem. The React Hook `useEffect()` calls a function whenever a prop changes. Therefore I defined a prop that indicates whether to submit or not. This prop will be passed through the components.

```js
import React, { useEffect, FC } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { Form, Input, Steps, Button, message } from "antd";

const { Step } = Steps;

class FirstStep extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shouldSubmitForm: props.shouldSubmitForm,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <BasicForm submit={this.props.shouldSubmitForm} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

class SecondStep extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p> Second Step </p>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const BasicForm: React.FC<any> = ({ submit }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onFinish = (values: any) => {
    console.log("Success:", values);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (submit === true) {
      form.submit();
    }
  }, [submit]);

  return (
    <Form name="basic" form={form} onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item label="Input" name="Input">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: 0,
      shouldSubmitForm: false,
    };
  }

  setCurrent = (value: number) => {
    this.setState({
      current: value,
    });
  };

  next() {
    this.setCurrent(this.state.current + 1);
  }

  prev() {
    this.setCurrent(this.state.current - 1);
  }

  steps = () => [
    {
      title: "1st Step",
      content: <FirstStep shouldSubmitForm={this.state.shouldSubmitForm} />,
      controlls: (
        <>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ shouldSubmitForm: true }, () => {
                this.next();
              });
            }}
          >
            Go to 2nd Step
          </Button>
        </>
      ),
    },
    {
      title: "2nd Step",
      content: <SecondStep />,
      controlls: (
        <>
          <Button style={{ margin: "0 8px" }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
            Go to 1st Step
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => message.success("Processing complete!")}
          >
            Finish
          </Button>
        </>
      ),
    },
  ];

  render() {
    let current = this.state.current;

    return (
      <>
        <Steps current={this.state.current}>
          {this.steps().map((item) => (
            <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </Steps>
        <div className="steps-content">{this.steps()[current].content}</div>
        <div className="steps-action">{this.steps()[current].controlls}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I advice you tu use react hooks everywhere!

Answer (score -1):

```
const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({});
const [form] = Form.useForm();

<Form
  form={form}
  onValuesChange={(_, values) => setFormValues(prevState => ({...prevState, ...values}))}
>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explanation, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explanation of your possible solution.